# SSMS - insert data through Edit top 200 in GUI, restricted by GUID

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In some cases i work directly with data through the Edit top 200 (or what it is set to) in SSMS.
I find it particularly useful when I get some sort of data that is pre-worked through Excel or similar from our customers and the volume is low.

But in come cases we have columns that are of type UniqueIdentifier (GUIDs) that are required which I else would use NewID() to generate when writing SQL directly.

So I have all information I need to just copy/paste data from lets say a sheet of excel into the GUI in SSMS "Edit top 200.." except from a column at will define a new GUID.
I can't just leave it empty/NULL either, that will generate an error message.

The embedded example tries to show what I mean. The first row is already present with a GUID (#2) and have data for the rest also (#1). So I have data for every column that is needed for those under #1 with red square, but if I put in such data in an empty row I will need to create a GUID in the first empty column under #2.

Have anyone seen a way to achieve what I try to describe above? Is there a way to get the GUI to somehow generate a NewID() in such columns?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no way to do a `INSERT INTO table (guid, val) VALUES (NEWID(), 1)` style `INSERT` through the UI.

Maybe changing the table definition in such a way, that the guid column contains a `DEFAULT(NEWID())`? That way you can just ignore the column in the GUI. Although you have to hit `Ctrl`+`R` (Execute SQL) to see the guids that got genereated.

[Update 01/10/2023]

There is another way, using a `VIEW`. Create a view for the table selecting all the fields you want to insert. Then create an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` `TRIGGER` on this view and you can use the Edit top 200 GUI on the view to insert data into the table.

```
-- table for holding the data
CREATE TABLE dbo.dummy (guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL, val INT NOT NULL);
GO

-- view for inserting purposes
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW dbo.dummy_view
AS
SELECT val
FROM   dbo.dummy;
GO

-- trigger that sets the guid values
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.dummy_insert
ON dbo.dummy_view
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.dummy (guid, val)
    SELECT NEWID(),
           Inserted.val
    FROM   Inserted;
END;
```